# SQL database is not getting updated while inserting from C# program

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I am new to C# and databases. I am connecting to my local database server using `CreateConnection()` method. I am trying to insert data into database table. When I read this data from SQL Server Management Studio using select query I am not able to get data back from table. However, I am able to read this data when I execute sql query from C# program. I doubt that the table that my C# program is accessing and the table created in SQL Server Management Studio  are not same even if they have same path and same name.

Code for `CreateConnection`:

```
    public void CreateConnection()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CreateConnection");

        myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local); Database=MyServerDB;Server=ATLW732FV000169\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True; connection timeout=30");
        {
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Code for SQL query:

```
primary_cmd = "INSERT INTO flightData (flightNum, Country) VALUES ('555','xyz');"

using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(primary_cmd, myConnection))
{
    try
    {
        int rows = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();                                        
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

I am not getting any kind of exception while inserting data into database. when I run same insert query in SQL Server Management Studio it works fine and inserts data in table. Additionally, I am able to read the inserted data from table from C# program. It looks like C# is connecting to some temporary database table and inserting into it.

Comment: What is the datatype of the flightNum field in the database?

Comment: All datatype in my table are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your connection string is wrong as it is not making the connection you are expecting. Everything else seems right. I don't think I have ever seen DataSource=(local) and Server=... in the same connection string. Maybe try something like:

```
new SQLConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=MyServerDB;server=(local)")
```

Or:

```
new SQLConnection("SERVER=ATLW732FV000169\\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=MyServerDB")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps implicit transactions are off in your database. In this case you need to commit the transaction by excuting another command:

```
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: I tried BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT TRANSACTION for executing SQL query, still it is not working.